# Python lists into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists:

```
['Slovenia', 'Turkey', 'Ukraine', 'Ukraine', 'Turkey']

['BMW Slovenia', 'Tesla Turkey', 'Opel Ukraine', 'Ford Ukraine', 'Fiat Turkey']
```

And I need to turn them into a dictionary with a list, where a country can have more than one item.

I want my dictionary to look like this:

```
{
    'Slovenia': ['BMW Slovenia'],
    'Turkey': ['Tesla Turkey','Fiat Turkey'],
    'Ukraine':['Opel Ukraine','Ford Ukraine']
}
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension. Note that this works even if the lists are of different length:

```
l1 = ['Slovenia', 'Turkey', 'Ukraine', 'Ukraine', 'Turkey']
l2 = ['BMW Slovenia', 'Tesla Turkey', 'Opel Ukraine', 'Ford Ukraine', 'Fiat Turkey']
out = {k: [c for c in l2 if k in c] for k in set(l1)}
```

For your specific case, you can also use `zip` (because the list lengths match) and `dict.setdefault`:

```
out = {}
for k,v in zip(l1,l2):
    out.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Output:

```
{'Slovenia': ['BMW Slovenia'],
 'Turkey': ['Tesla Turkey', 'Fiat Turkey'],
 'Ukraine': ['Opel Ukraine', 'Ford Ukraine']}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip` to pair the two lists, and a `collections.defaultdict` to store the results

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = ['Slovenia', 'Turkey', 'Ukraine', 'Ukraine', 'Turkey']
y = ['BMW Slovenia', 'Tesla Turkey', 'Opel Ukraine', 'Ford Ukraine', 'Fiat Turkey']

result = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in zip(x, y):
    result[key].append(val)

print(result)
# {'Slovenia': ['BMW Slovenia'],
# 'Turkey': ['Tesla Turkey', 'Fiat Turkey'],
# 'Ukraine': ['Opel Ukraine', 'Ford Ukraine']}
```